# How to calculate class-specific accuracy on PCA?

Tags: pca

I have implemented PCA at Matlab. I just did dimensionality reduction (I don't use but I have class labels in my data set). My aim is to calculate overall accuracy and class-specific accuracy. I know that I can calculate overall (training data set and test data set) accuracy with PoV (Proportion of Variance Explained)--if I am wrong you can explain it, you are welcome--but I don't know how to calculate class-specific accuracy. It sounds to me that each class accuracy is the same as overall accuracy.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Principal component analysis (PCA) is a dimensionality reduction technique. It is not a classification technique. So, what are the "classes"? What is "accuracy" (overall or not). Proportion of Variance explained is just what it says ... proportion of variance explained. That's not accuracy, that's a measure of how much variance has been explained.

Comment: Even I don't use class labels I have them. If PoV is high then when can eliminate some dimensions, is that right?

Comment: If PoV is high, it means that some dimensions can be ignored without losing much information. 

You can use the *results* of PCA to do classification - but PCA itself doesn't do it.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question. I know it is a dimensionality reduction technique rather than a classification method. However it is a question given for me and I have to calculate accuracy for it and for each classes.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to calculate class-specific accuracy. It sounds to me that each class accuracy is the same as overall accuracy.

No, class-specific accuracy it is not necessarily the same as overall accuracy. In addition, you need to be careful of the actual definition: there are several possibilities for both terms.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_binary_classification) is a good starting point. It is about binary classification, i.e. two classes that are mutually exclusive.

Depending on your field and problem,

- sensitivity and specificity
- positive and negative predictive value
- producer's or consumer's accuracy
- precision or recall

are names for different types of class-specific classification accuracy.

The overall accurracy may be the

- average sensitivity (for binary classification, you can use average of sensitivity and specificity)
- average positive predictive value (for binary classification, you can use average of pos. and  neg. predictive value).
- the average may be weighted to give each test sample *or* each class the same weight, *or* weight each class according to its prior probability (prevalence).

Extensions for more complicated situations, like

- multiple classes,
- classes not mutually exclusive (one-class classifiers) 
  exist.

**Bottomline:** you need to define carefully what kind of accuracy you want to measure. In general, you'll want to report at least two performance measures (the pairs in the first list are common pairs of measures to be reported together).

#### Proportion of variance

doesn't need to have anything to do with the classification accuracy, here's an example in R:

```
> df <- data.frame (x = rnorm (100, sd=10), y = sample (0:1, 100, replace=TRUE))
> pca <- prcomp (df)
> pca
Standard deviations:
[1] 10.1435332  0.5011764

Rotation:
           PC1          PC2
x -0.999995404 -0.003031692
y  0.003031692 -0.999995404
> pca$sdev^2 / sum (pca$sdev^2) # % variance
[1] 0.997564748 0.002435252
> plot (pca$x, asp=1, pch = 19, col = df$y + 1)
```

[image: pc1 doesn't help classification]

The first PC explains more than 99.7% of the total variance, yet it doesn't help at all for the classification into red or black.
But the 0.25% of variance in the second component allow perfect classification.

Answer (score 0):

I've used my intuition trying to understand your question:
the factors resulted explain xx% of variance and your question is how to depict the % of variance explained by each factor.
The answer: plain vanilla SPSS throw this factors in descending order of their % variance explained:
[image]

If you want to do this in R it is easier but depending on R package used output might not be ordered...

Comment: Welcome to our site! Could you please elaborate on how your answer addresses the question about "accuracy"? How, exactly, is that related to percent of variance explained?